# How to make buttons closer?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

i'm trying to make a simple calculator using Tkinter, but the buttons are too far apart. This is my full code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")

display = Entry(root, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 30), bg = "black", fg = "white", bd = 30).grid(columnspan = 4)

Button7 = Button(root, bd = 10, text= "7", padx = 16, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20), bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 0, row = 1)

Button8 = Button(root, bd = 10, text = "8", padx = 16, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20), bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 1, row = 1)

Division = Button(root, bd = 10, text = "/", padx = 16, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20), bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 2, row = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

[This occours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IviUN.png)

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: try using a smaller value for "bd" maybe 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is because the entry is wider than the three buttons. You can set a smaller width and then let the grid geometry manager expand it to cover the width of the buttons with `sticky = 'ew'`. Also you might want to set `justify = 'right'` in the entry or it will look funny.

I included some text in the example below:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")

txt = StringVar()   # StringVar to hold entry text
txt.set('123456')   # Set StringVar

display = Entry(root, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 30), 
                bg = "black", fg = "white", bd = 30, textvariable = txt,
                # Set width and justify for entry + sticky to fill available space
                width = 1, justify = 'right').grid(columnspan = 4, sticky = 'ew')

Button7 = Button(root, bd = 10, text= "7", padx = 16,
                 font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20),
                 bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 0, row = 1)

Button8 = Button(root, bd = 10, text = "8", padx = 16,
                 font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20),
                 bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 1, row = 1)

Division = Button(root, bd = 10, text = "/", padx = 16,
                  font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20),
                  bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 2, row = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sticky="ew"` and adjust `padx` in every `grid(...)` for buttons to expand the buttons to fill the grid cell.  Also you assigned the result of `grid(...)` to all button variables which always be `None`.  So separate the `grid(...)` function from the creation function, for example:

```
Button7 = Button(root, bd=10, text="7", padx=16, font=("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 20), bg="black", fg="white")
Button7.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=2)
```